# Text field value. Display one value send another to the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a text field where I want to display a value to the user but send a different value to the server. How can I do this using `form_field`?

```
<td><%= f.text_field :code, value: "Sarah", class: "account-rep-code", readonly: true %></td>
```

This will display `Sarah` and send `Sarah` to the server on submit. I want to display the value `Sarah` to the user but send `Steve` to the server to be saved to the database for `code`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: did you try using a hidden field ?

Comment: Easiest way would be to replace your text_field for a "normal" text input, and use a hidden_field helper to send the value of `:code`. Other way would be to change with JS that value before doing the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, you can try with `hidden_field` like after the `read-only` filed you can declare a `hidden_field` like this

```
<%= f.text_field :code, value: "Sarah", class: "account-rep-code", readonly: true %>
<%= f.hidden_field :code, value: "Steve" %>
```

generated HTML

```
<input value="Sarah" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="user[code]" id="user_code">
<input value="Steve" type="hidden" name="user[code]" id="user_code">
```

look after submitted the form

```
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("code", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["code", "Steve"], ["created_at", "2018-04-16 03:19:58.258904"], ["updated_at", "2018-04-16 03:19:58.258904"]]
```

it's saving `steve`